# Calculating the connectance of a matrix iteratively

Tags: performance, graph, matrix, r, simulation

I have a performance issue in R. I have a function that iterates over a dataframe for different levels of "site" and "method". The function samples 1:1000 interactions (rows), converts these to matrices and calculates a value of connectance for each matrix. This is repeated n times. The function runs exactly as I want it, returning a dataframe with connectance values for 1 to 1000 interactions when repeated a small number of times. The problem is when I increase the number of repetitions (say to 100) the function runs progressively slower.

```
df <- read.table(text = "bird_sp plant_sp value site method
                    1  species_a  plant_a     1    a      m
                    2  species_a  plant_a     1    a      m
                    3  species_b  plant_b     1    a      m
                    4  species_b  plant_b     1    a      m
                    5  species_c  plant_c     1    a      m
                    6  species_a  plant_a     1    b      m
                    7  species_a  plant_a     1    b      m
                    8  species_b  plant_b     1    b      m
                    9  species_b  plant_b     1    b      m
                    10 species_c  plant_c     1    b      m
                    11 species_a  plant_a     1    a      f
                    12 species_a  plant_a     1    a      f
                    13 species_b  plant_b     1    a      f
                    14 species_b  plant_b     1    a      f
                    15 species_c  plant_c     1    a      f
                    16 species_a  plant_a     1    b      f
                    17 species_a  plant_a     1    b      f
                    18 species_b  plant_b     1    b      f
                    19 species_b  plant_b     1    b      f
                    20 species_c  plant_c     1    b      f", header = TRUE)

xDegrees <-function(df, size, numRep){

  #Loading required library
  require(bipartite)

  #Creating vector of unique combinations
  df <- within(df, {SiteMethod <- paste(site, method, sep = ":")})

  #Creating empty dataframe
  connectMatrix <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(0,4), ncol = 4))
  colnames(connectMatrix) <- c("Site","Method","Size","connectance")

  #Beginning of matrix
  k <- 1

  #Beginning subsetting loop
  for(i in 1:length(unique(df$SiteMethod))){

  #subsetting dataset
  dfSub <- subset(df, SiteMethod == unique(df$SiteMethod)[i])

  #Storing site for matrix
  site <- as.character(dfSub[1,]$site)

  #Storing method for matrix
  method <- as.character(dfSub[1,]$method)

  for(l in 1:numRep){
    #Beginning calculation loop
    for(j in 1:length(size)){

    #show progress
    print(paste("S:M", i,j , "completed", sep = " "))

    #The size being calculated
    subSize <- size[j]

    #generate random samples and convert to matrices
    rows <- sample(1:nrow(dfSub), subSize, replace=T)
    intlist <- dfSub[rows,]
    mat <- with(intlist, tapply(value, list(plant_sp, bird_sp), sum))
    mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0

    #network level function to calculate connectance
    con <- networklevel(mat,  index = c("connectance"))

    #Stitch matrix together
    connectMatrix[k,] <- c(site, method, subSize, con)

    #Update row
    k <- k + 1
      }
    }
  }

#Return complete matrix
return(connectMatrix)

}

#run the function. 1:1000 interactions, 100 reps
stuff <- xDegrees(df, size = 1:1000, numRep = 100)
```

Any ideas on how to speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `by` to slice your dataframes by the *site* and *method* factors and then pass dataframe subsets into an adjusted *xDegrees* function. Other than the group slice, the other major change is combining `for` loops with `rep` and passing result into one `sapply` call. Below of course is not tested since you do not provide a reproducible example.

```
# Loading required library
require(bipartite)

xDegrees <-function(dfSub, size, numRep){

  # Retrieving current site
  s <- as.character(dfSub$site[[1]])

  # Retrieving current method
  m <- as.character(dfSub$method[[1]])

  # Build large vector of all random runs
  sample_iter <- rep(seq_along(size), numRep)  

  # Generate random samples and convert to matrices
  con_vec <- sapply(sample_iter, function(i) {
     rows <- sample(1:nrow(dfSub), i, replace=T))

     intlist <- dfSub[rows,]
     mat <- with(intlist, tapply(value, list(plant_sp, bird_sp), sum))
     mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0

     # network level function to calculate connectance
     con <- networklevel(mat,  index = c("connectance"))
  })

  # size is a multiple of con_vec (whose length = size * numRep)
  return(data.frame(method = m, site = s, subsize = size, con = con_vec))
}

df_List <- by(df, df[,c("site", "method")], FUN=function(d)
                   xDegrees(d, size = 1:1000, numRep = 100))

finald_df <- do.call(rbind, df_List)
```

Answer (score 3):

Without installing `bipartite` and getting into the exact details of what the actual calculations are looking to do, there are a few things that jump out at me that might help you.

### Growing the Object (connectMatrix)

It looks like you're in [Circle 2 - Growing Objects of the R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/).
Specifically, the line where you've got:

```
#Stitch matrix together  
connectMatrix[k,] <- c(site, method, subSize, con)
```

In that scenario, every time you add another row to the connectMatrix, you're expanding and fragmenting the memory you're using, which as you've observed starts out okay but then starts to really drag. Here's another [resource on that same issue](https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/15-supp-loops-in-depth/), and a much less intricate [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778510/efficiently-adding-or-removing-elements-to-a-vector-or-list-in-r).

### nested `for` loops

You've got three layers of nested `for` loops

```
for(i in 1:length(unique(df$SiteMethod))){

    #subsetting dataset
    ...
    ...
    ...


    for(l in 1:numRep){
        #Beginning calculation loop
        for(j in 1:length(size)){

        ...
        ...

        }
    }
```

The outside for loop jumps out at me as something the `plyr` package might be good for -- essentially it looks like you're splitting the main dataframe into subsets, then doing things to it (the meat of your second and third for loops). Basically, `plyr` was designed for splitting-applying-and combining, and there's [a really great paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v040i01) on how to implement it.

You may be able to do two (or maybe even three) layers of splitting-applying-combining.

If the data lend themselves to grouping operations, those tend to help, too, but it doesn't seem like it based on the comments in the code.

### Parallel processing

If, after you've optimized for not growing the object and chunked the code for splitting/combining (or another method of getting to the same outcome), you're still not at the level of performance you're looking for, you can journey into parallel application.

Basically, parallel application works well when you're using `apply` or `plyr` approaches and you can convert over to [`mcmapply`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/parallel/versions/3.4.0/topics/mclapply) or one of the other `parallel` approaches.

For example, we use `mcmapply` in production at work to take a 30 minute process and trim it down to about 6 minutes. Parallel processing tends to be worth it (in my personal experience) only once you've done everything else you can to get to the best speed you can without parallelizing - it tends to be more work to get it right, and, as a bonus, once you've done the other things it tends to make it easier to convert the process to run on multiple cores.

Finally, [Efficient R](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/) is a good general resource on optimizing R processes.

Comment: upvoted for good links